# Getting Wrong Answer in "Longest non regular parentheses sub-sequence "codechef june cook off

Tags: algorithm

I attended a programming competition(it has ended now). I don't know why my solution is giving WA, I read the editorial, saw other people solution but unable to find a flaw in my solution. Obviously I am missing somewhere. Please help!

[Question Link](http://www.codechef.com/problems/ANKPAREN)

[My Solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/7273454)

**My approach**

If the pattern is non regular, answer is the same. Otherwise answer would be of length 1 less than the original pattern. Now the 1st lexicographic-ally smallest pattern can be obtained by removing one of the ')' from the first chunk(continuous sequence) of ')' in original pattern. 2nd lexicographic-ally smallest pattern can be obtained by removing one of the ')' from the second(if any) chunk(continuous sequence) of ')' in original pattern.And so on. And then say there are 'x' chunks of ')'. And we need to find kth lexicographic-ally pattern such that (k>x). For this case we move from backward, so for (x+1)th smallest pattern we remove '(' from first chunk of '(' (moving backward to front), for (x+2)nd we remove '(' from second chunk, and so on. 
The same logic is explained in tutorial [here](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/71904/ankparen-editorial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See I know you will feel bad when I will tell you what is wrong in your answer.

But the only thing wrong is you using gets(). Its 2015 no one uses it.
I changed that to a scanf statement i.e delete this part of your code and

```
get(s);
get(s);
scan("%d",&k);
```

write this instead.

```
scan("%s%d",s,&k);
```

And Your code will be accepted. Next time try avoiding use of gets. use scanf, cin, something else.

Comment: `gets` may be bad coding practice (though hardly worse than your `%s` in `scanf`), but it should still work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, why gets didn't work. I mean I've using it since 3-4 years now. I don't get it.

Comment: gets is considered dangerous so its not clear how online judge will handle it. Most of the servers have different ways of maintaining there security. Whereas in scanf, cin u know that it will take a single word and would break after a space or \n. u might use fgets or getline.

Comment: `%s` in `scanf` does the same work but most of the online judges behave normally for this as one space and scanf would shut up but most of the judges have some extra security setup for `gets()` so it might not work as it is working on your PC.